# What is the meaning of "/bin/exec -c --"?

Tags: linux, bash

I see this command is used in s6-overlay, for example [here](https://github.com/just-containers/s6-overlay/blob/master/builder/overlay-rootfs/usr/bin/with-contenv):

```
#!/bin/execlineb -S0
importas -D 0 S6_KEEP_ENV S6_KEEP_ENV
ifelse { s6-test ${S6_KEEP_ENV} -eq 0 }
{
  /bin/exec -c --
  /usr/bin/justc-envdir -- /var/run/s6/container_environment
  /bin/exec --
  $@
}

$@
```

What does it do?

Comment: soooo see `help exec`? Or `exec --help`? Is `execlineb` bash?

Comment: @KamilCuk, man pages don't reveal much, e.g. https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/exec.1p.html (just says that running without a command has unspecified behavior, not what the specified behavior is)

Comment: So you have to see your specific implementation about implementation-specific behavior. So see `/bin/exec --help` and `help exec`. Yes, in POSIX standard exec is unspecified, so the question is what your specific `/bin/exec` does. What system is running on "s6-overlay"? Find out what system is that -> find source code of `exec` program -> inspect nd find out what `-c` does. You tagged bash, so __in bash__ you can see it here: https://github.com/bminor/bash/blob/master/builtins/exec.def#L34 . But `/bin/exec` is not a builtin call, it's `execlineb` (what is execlineb?), so you have track it.

Comment: Hmmm... `exec` is a bash-builtin. The `-c` specifies the command will be executed with an empty environment, and `--` indicates end-of-arguments. Also "*If command is not specified, any redirections take effect in the current shell, and the return status is 0.*"